# how to get next object value on keyup event on card with vue and vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, addeventlistener, keyup, vuetify.js

**UPDATE:**

I realized that my component needed to be wrapped in a div then I added the following code:

```
<div @keyup.down="keyFire(1)" @keyup.up="keyFire(-1)">
  <multiple-cards
    v-for="(card, i) in multiCards"
    :card="card"
    :i="i"
    @click.native="activateCard(card, i)"
    tabindex="0"
    ref="cards"
    >
    </multiple-cards>
</div>

  keyFire(iterator) {
    const currentActive = this.cardActive;
    const newIdx = currentActive + iterator;
    const newCard = this.multiCards[newIdx];
    this.activateCard(newCard, newIdx);
  }
```

Then I had an issue where the first card wasn't being focused for the user to just be able to use the arrow keys because of my logic so I ended up doing

```
this.$refs.cards[0].$el.focus();
```

---

Original Question:

I have a Vue component that is a v-for loop of Vuetify cards. I am trying to use the @keyup event listener to move up and down the cards with arrow keys. If I do a global event listener I can get the keyup and down event, but that doesn't help me since it doesn't seem to know which card index its on or where to move up or down. I've tried @keyup.native.up, @keyup.native.down and versions without the .native

Here is a codepen showing the basic issue:
https://codepen.io/AleaQ/pen/rdGxEz

The actual code looks more like this:

**Parent component**

```
<multiple-cards
v-for="(card, i) in multiCards"
:card="card"
:i="i"
@click.native="activateCard(card, i)"
@keyup.native="activateCard"
>
</multiple-cards>
```

**Child component:**

```
<v-card
id="mCard"
:class="{'border', cardActive}"
>
</v-card>
```

**event listener:**

```
mounted() {
window.addEventListener('keyup', this.activateCard)
}
```

I know Vuetify doesn't have a listener on their card component, so I'm not sure if that is an automatic deal breaker or if there is some other way to achieve this with pure javascript.  I cannot use JQuery.

Comment: so it turns out in my own code I didn't put keyup on a div wrapped around the multipe-cards.  I wrapped a div around it and put @keyup.down="keyFire(1)" @keyup.up="keyFire(-1)"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the a event when only sending in the "card" to the click method. Modified your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoJYzo) with some comments explaining the things i've added.

mosty notebly I pass the event with the keyup event in the template

```html
<div v-for="(card, i) in objData" 
  :key="i"
  @keyup="eventListenCard(card, event)"
  @click="showCurrObj(card)"
  tabindex="0"
  id="answerCard"
  ref="cards"
>
```

And then in the in the `eventListen` method I use the target of the event to fetch the next element to focus.

```
eventListen(val, event) {
    ...
    event.target.nextElementSibling.focus();
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help on this I think I was able to see I was focusing on the wrong thing.